# How to copy games data

Tags: copy-paste

Can I copy the data of a game and transfer from my old tablet to my new tablet and if so, how do I do that? Both tablets are samsung tab4 10.1 
( my old one doesn't have an sdcard )

Comment: What Android versions are running on the devices? Are they rooted?

Comment: By data you refer to APK and its OBB files (I mean, data as you downloaded it) or the data that the game have generated like score leader databases, game characters, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the game, the save data might be saved inside the /data/ partition. If you want to copy files from that partition you need root access.
Some games offer a function to save the game data to some online account (Facebook, Google Play etc).
I suggest you first check for an online method and then think about rooting both devices to copy the files.

Comment: *If* one must root the device just to be able to copy *user data*, then the design is very broken!